# AsyncTask to Azure - Server failed to authenticate the request

Tags: java, android, azure

```
try
    {
        // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("config");

        // Loop through each blob item in the container.
        // If the item is a blob, not a virtual directory.
        for (ListBlobItem blobItem : container.listBlobs()) {
            if (blobItem instanceof CloudBlob) {
                // Download the item and save it to a file with the same name.
                CloudBlob blob = (CloudBlob) blobItem;
                if(blob.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(configFileName)) {
                    blob.download(new java.io.FileOutputStream(HashOutConfig.ROOT_PATH + "/" + configFileName));
                    return HashOutConfig.ROOT_PATH + "/" + configFileName;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (Throwable th)
    {
        // Output the stack trace.
        th.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG,"Exception==>>>",th);
        Log.e(TAG,"Error while dowloading file from blob storage"+th.getMessage().toString());
        return null;
    }
```

```
10-06 12:16:26.312 4491-5605/com.microsoft.hashout W/System.err: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
10-06 12:16:26.312 4491-5605/com.microsoft.hashout W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:113)
10-06 12:16:26.313 4491-5605/com.microsoft.hashout W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.hashout.task.DownloadFromBlobStorage.downloadFromAzureBlobStorage(DownloadFromBlobStorage.java:68)
10-06 12:16:26.313 4491-5605/com.microsoft.hashout W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.hashout.task.DownloadFromBlobStorage.doInBackground(DownloadFromBlobStorage.java:38)
10-06 12:16:26.313 4491-5605/com.microsoft.hashout W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.hashout.task.DownloadFromBlobStorage.doInBackground(DownloadFromBlobStorage.java:20)
10-06 12:16:26.317 4491-5605/com.microsoft.hashout W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
10-06 12:16:26.317 4491-5605/com.microsoft.hashout W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-06 12:16:26.317 4491-5605/com.microsoft.hashout W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
10-06 12:16:26.318 4491-5605/com.microsoft.hashout W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
10-06 12:16:26.318 4491-5605/com.microsoft.hashout W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
10-06 12:16:26.318 4491-5605/com.microsoft.hashout W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-06 12:16:26.318 4491-5605/com.microsoft.hashout W/System.err: Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
10-06 12:16:26.319 4491-5605/com.microsoft.hashout W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305)
10-06 12:16:26.319 4491-5605/com.microsoft.hashout W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:175)
10-06 12:16:26.319 4491-5605/com.microsoft.hashout W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:109)
10-06 12:16:26.320 4491-5605/com.microsoft.hashout W/System.err:    ... 9 more
```

Comment: What is the question? You've copied a partial section of code and an error log. The error clearly says authentication failed

Answer (score 1):

`Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.`

Wrong credentials maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, this issue may be due to the storageConnectionString.
You could inspect whether you copy the right account key.

Hope it helps. Any concerns, please feel free to let me know.